# Black bar at the bottom of my screen on new MacBook 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, touch-bar

I have a black bar at the bottom of my screen which changes as I use the Touch Bar, but cannot remove it. It is eating up my screen space and I cannot see the Dock.

Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image: Black Bar at bottom of screen]

Answer (score 1):

Finaly after seeing [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/269570/71490)I understand what it is you are seeing.
It appears to be the touchbar zoom functionality.
You can find this and deactivate it by **rightclicking the system preferences item**.
Then select **accessibility**>**zoom** and **deselect touchbar zoom**.
[image: touchbar zoom]
**Be sure to use the rightclick method to go to accessibility, otherwise the touchbar zoom option wont show up.**